# NSCFArray objectForKey crash?

Tags: ios, encryption, nsarray, sigabrt, property-list

I am trying to do something relatively simple. I have a .plist in my bundle and I am trying to save it to the documents directory with encryption. Now before I tried added encryption, it worked fine. However a new crash has arose.

This is how I save my .plist:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Hi.plist"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) {
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GameSave" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSData *plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:bundle];
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:plistData toFile:path];
    plistData = [plistData AES256EncryptWithKey:@"536335"];
    [plistData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

Then this is how I retrieve my .plist (and later change a value and re-save)

```
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Hi.plist"];

        //Get array and then current level dict
        NSData *plistData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        plistData = [plistData AES256DecryptWithKey:@"1111"];

        NSMutableArray *savegameArray = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:plistData] mutableCopy];
        int objectIndex = [Singleton sharedInstance].levelNumber - 1;
        NSMutableDictionary *levelDict = [[savegameArray objectAtIndex:objectIndex] mutableCopy];
        [levelDict setObject:videoID forKey:@"RecordingURL"];
        //Now put new dict back in array
        [savegameArray replaceObjectAtIndex:objectIndex withObject:levelDict];

        NSData *savedarrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:savegameArray];
        savedarrayData = [savedarrayData AES256EncryptWithKey:@"1111"];
        [savedarrayData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

However, in the read code every time I get to this line: `NSMutableArray *savegameArray = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:plistData] mutableCopy];` There is a SIGABRT crash which prints:

> '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x16604140'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you actually archiving the plist before you save it? Maybe unnecessary, but I do this for safety anytime we are going to unarchive it later.

Comment: It's just in my bundle. I am copying first from the bundle to the documents directory while encrypting it. Then the bottom block of code is the code to decrypt it and retrieve the values from within it.

Comment: Well, you're trying to do objectForKey on an NSArray.  As to why that is, I can't say.

Comment: Right, but you're unarchiving something later without archiving it before saving it (Probably unnecessary like I said for strict .plist) but it's safe.

Comment: BTW don't put your encryption/decryption keys hardcoded in a string like that. Very easy to find these in the app binary.

Comment: @troop231 It seems you can see what I'm doing wrong. When you mean archive, what exactly do you mean? I am saving it to the documents directory. Unless you mean something else? Oh I didn't know that, should I make a random digit and save it via user defaults? This is the first time I have done encryption so I need all the help I can get.

Comment: Comment to first question, do this before saving: `[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:plistData toFile:filePath];` Second comment: Use an `NSMutableString` and build the encryption key string at runtime by appending strings to it. `[mutableString appendString:@"k"];[mutableString appendString:@"e"];[mutableString appendString:@"y"];`

Comment: Ok I will fix the second issue afterwards. Do you mean to do the archiveRootObject before the encryption or after? I just tried putting it afterwards and the same crash still happens.

Comment: Also @troop231 for the mutable string. What is the intended way to save it securely? That way I can access it wherever I need to decrypt the data.

Comment: @iBradApps, you would archive the object before encrypting, then you would decrypt the NSData, then unarchive it later. Also, you don't need to save your `NSMutableString` anywhere, that's why we're using it.

Comment: @troop231 I posted my updated save code above but it still crashes! I honestly am not sure why its not working. Whats wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58208/discussion-between-troop231-and-ibrad-apps).

Comment: Did my answer work for you or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discovered through our chat, we had to first convert the decrypted `NSData` object to a proper `NSPropertyListSerialization` serialization.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Hi.plist"];

NSData *plistData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSData *newData = [plistData AES256DecryptWithKey:@"1111"];

NSPropertyListFormat format;

NSMutableArray *savegameArray = [[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:newData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:nil]mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"Array: %@",savegameArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to allocate memory to your NSMutableArray like... 
   NSMutableArray *arrayName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
Until you do that crash will arose..

Hope this is helpful.

Thanks,
Rajesh..